# Speeding up reduce?

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning

I have the following reduce which has been running now for three/four hours. Is there any way to speed it up?

```
Reduce[{Sqrt[q/(2 x)] + 2 b + 2 (q Sqrt[q (q + 2 x b)])/x < f && 
q > Log[3] + 2 Log[2] && 2 b < f < 1 && 0 < b && 
x > ((1 + 16 f + Sqrt[1 + 32 f]) Log[6])/(4 f^2)}, x]
```

Comment: Since all your variables appear to be >=0 and you only have two square roots containing x you might be able to carefully do repeated squarings to get rid of both of those square roots. When I did this I ended up with the expected quartic equation and Reduce was then able to rapidly able to give me the four (large complicated) Root objects. I think those four roots give you the boundaries on the intervals where your inequality is true.

Comment: @Bill: can you please explain why I have to be "careful" in the repeated squaring? I was thinking of just computing the squares using Mathematica itself, but I guess that would not be really "careful". Otherwise, I'm thinking of replacing Sqrt[x] with another variable y, and then feed that to Mathematica.

Comment: If I am manually doing a sequence of squarings and rearrangements on a complicated expression then I have to wonder whether I might have either lost some roots, created some spurious roots that didn't exist before or made some other algebraic mistakes in my manual process. Thus my warning, especially for new users.

Comment: @bill: Did you actually try to do what you suggest with the above equation? I'm asking because your first comment seems to suggest that you did, and I just tried to do what you suggest, and I ended up with a quartic equation, but Mathematica still isn't solving it. I ended up with (see next comment)

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8636303/695132  In particular: "The cylindrical algebraic decomposition (CAD), which Mma uses, scales with a double exponential behavior on the number of variables."  There were discussions on this on MathGroup many years ago, which you may want to search for.

Comment: Reduce[{16 q^8 - 4 q^5 x + 64 b q^7 x + (q^2 x^2)/4 - 8 b q^4 x^2 - 
     32 b^2 q^4 x^2 + 32 b f q^4 x^2 - 8 f^2 q^4 x^2 + 
     64 b^2 q^6 x^2 - 4 b^2 q x^3 + 4 b f q x^3 - f^2 q x^3 - 
     64 b^3 q^3 x^3 + 64 b^2 f q^3 x^3 - 16 b f^2 q^3 x^3 + 
     16 b^4 x^4 - 32 b^3 f x^4 + 24 b^2 f^2 x^4 - 8 b f^3 x^4 + 
     f^4 x^4 >= 0 && 2 b < f < 1 && 0 < b && 
   x > ((1 + 16 f + Sqrt[1 + 32 f]) Log[6])/(4 f^2) && 
   q > Log[3] + 2 Log[2]}, x]

Comment: E.g. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/5QQB2iKLQU8/h_GC7-qGyKMJ

Comment: @Szabolcs: thank you.